# OpenGL 3.2 not working on mac os x with GLFW, can't draw anything

Tags: macos, opengl, glfw

I'm setting up a OpenGL 3.2 Xcode project using GLFW and GLEW. I've added the GLFW include path to the header paths, and added libglfw.a to the project. I've also added the cocoa and OpenGL frameworks. Then I try to use this sample code:

main.cpp:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glfw.h>
#include "math3d.h"

GLuint VBO;


static const char* pVS = "                                                    \n\
#version 150                                                                  \n\
\n\
layout (location = 0) in vec3 Position;                                       \n\
\n\
void main()                                                                   \n\
{                                                                             \n\
gl_Position = vec4(0.5 * Position.x, 0.5 * Position.y, Position.z, 1.0);  \n\
}";

static const char* pFS = "                                                    \n\
#version 150                                                                  \n\
\n\
out vec4 FragColor;                                                           \n\
\n\
void main()                                                                   \n\
{                                                                             \n\
FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);                                     \n\
}";

static void RenderScene()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glfwSwapBuffers();
}



static void CreateVertexBuffer()
{
    Vector3f Vertices[3];
    Vertices[0] = Vector3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
    Vertices[1] = Vector3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
    Vertices[2] = Vector3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Vertices), Vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}

static void AddShader(GLuint ShaderProgram, const char* pShaderText, GLenum ShaderType)
{
    GLuint ShaderObj = glCreateShader(ShaderType);

    if (ShaderObj == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error creating shader type %d\n", ShaderType);
        return ;
    }

    const GLchar* p[1];
    p[0] = pShaderText;
    GLint Lengths[1];
    Lengths[0]= strlen(pShaderText);
    glShaderSource(ShaderObj, 1, p, Lengths);
    glCompileShader(ShaderObj);
    GLint success;
    glGetShaderiv(ShaderObj, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success) {
        GLchar InfoLog[1024];
        glGetShaderInfoLog(ShaderObj, 1024, NULL, InfoLog);
        fprintf(stderr, "Error compiling shader type %d: '%s'\n", ShaderType, InfoLog);
        return;
    }

    glAttachShader(ShaderProgram, ShaderObj);
}

static void CompileShaders()
{
    GLuint ShaderProgram = glCreateProgram();

    if (ShaderProgram == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error creating shader program\n");
        return;
    }

    AddShader(ShaderProgram, pVS, GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    AddShader(ShaderProgram, pFS, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    GLint Success = 0;
    GLchar ErrorLog[1024] = { 0 };

    glLinkProgram(ShaderProgram);
    glGetProgramiv(ShaderProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS, &Success);
    if (Success == 0) {
        glGetProgramInfoLog(ShaderProgram, sizeof(ErrorLog), NULL, ErrorLog);
        fprintf(stderr, "Error linking shader program: '%s'\n", ErrorLog);
        return;
    }

    glValidateProgram(ShaderProgram);
    glGetProgramiv(ShaderProgram, GL_VALIDATE_STATUS, &Success);
    if (!Success) {
        glGetProgramInfoLog(ShaderProgram, sizeof(ErrorLog), NULL, ErrorLog);
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid shader program: '%s'\n", ErrorLog);
        return;
    }

    glUseProgram(ShaderProgram);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glfwInit();
    glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
    glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE,GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwOpenWindow(600, 600, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, GLFW_WINDOW);

    GLenum err = glewInit();
    if (GLEW_OK != err)
    {
        /* Problem: glewInit failed, something is seriously wrong. */
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", glewGetErrorString(err));
    }


    CreateVertexBuffer();

    CompileShaders();
    glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
   while (1)
   {
       RenderScene();
   }

    return 0;
}
```

math3d.h:

```
#ifndef GLFWTest_math3d_h
#define GLFWTest_math3d_h

struct Vector3f
{
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;

    Vector3f()
    {
    }

    Vector3f(float _x, float _y, float _z)
    {
        x = _x;
        y = _y;
        z = _z;
    }
};
#endif
```

but nothing gets drawn, I only get a yellow window. Any Idea why this is happening? I'm using a mac book pro a year or so old with osx lion installed

Comment: For starters, can you try error checking with glGetError?

Comment: Okay, i get GL_INVALID_ENUM error after the glewInit call, and after CreateVertexBuffer(), CompileShader() and RenderScene(). (I haven't tracked in exactly which function calls inside that functions cause the errors, I think any OpenGL extension function call causes that error. It's estrange that glewInit causes a GL_INVALID_ENUM, but it doesn't return an error

Comment: I have read that glewInit generates a GL_INVALID_ENUM in opengl 3.2+ contexts, and that you need to specify glewExperimental=true before calling it, but I have tried doing that and the error persists

Comment: I've seen that after specifying glewExperimental=true I still get the GL_INVALID_ENUM, but I no longer get errors on CreateVertexBuffer() and CompileShader(), but I get GL_INVALID_OPERATIONs on glEnableVertexAttribArray(), glDrawArrays() and glDisableVertexAttribArray()

Comment: You are certain that the error is directly after enablevertexattrib? The doc says that can only happen if it's between glBegin and glEnd, which I don't see anywhere. The doc might be inaccurate, but just wanted to make sure.

Comment: Yes, I have tried puting a glGetError just before enabling and another one after, and the second one gives that error

Comment: First of all, Apple doesn't support layouts in shaders.  Use glBindAttribPointer with in variables.  Secondly, use glDrawArrays/glDrawElements.  I believe that Apple requires you to use them.  There are also a few other things, but in short, use a new tutorial.  The one you're using isn't gonna cut, especially with osx.  I would say http://www.opengl-tutorial.org is pretty decent, though you'll have to replace the layouts with in variables.

Comment: I'm already using glDrawArrays. I'll look into a new tutorial, but one question, does any of those problems justify the error I'm getting?